# How to cast from Stream to FileStream in C#

Tags: c#, casting, filestream, outputstream, mailmerge

I have a `Stream` type "outputStream" that I got from MailMerger that I need to return as `FileStream`.

I know that `FileStream` extends `Stream`, but is there a way to transfer content to Stream or maybe cast the type?

Any ideas on how to change the type?

```
        static FileStream IMailMergeService(Dictionary<string, string> dataSource, Stream stream)
        {
            var (outputStream, errors) = new MailMerger().Merge(stream, dataSource);

            return (FileStream)outputStream;
        }
```

[This is the MailMerger used](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailMerge/)

Comment: C# is strongly typed language. You can't cast dog to tomato, like in python or javascript, nor base Stream to FileStream.

Answer (score 0):

If you [look at the source](https://github.com/chrisfcarroll/MailMerge/blob/master/MailMerge/MailMerger.cs#L151) a `Stream.Null` which is of type `NullStream` is returned when an exception happens. So the first thing I would do is look at the exceptions you are getting:

```
foreach (var inner in errors.InnerExceptions)
{
    // Print them out somewhere or look at the exceptions when debugging
    Console.WriteLine(inner.ToString());
}
```

About your error message:

A `NullStream` is a sealed class that derives from `Stream`. A `FileStream` also derives from `Stream`, but a `FileStream` is not a `NullStream` and vice versa. It would be like saying a `Dog` is also a `Cat`, you cannot convert between the two (although they might both derive from the `Animal` class).

If you do not know what I mean when I say "is a relationship" when talking about types, these are the basics of object-oriented programming, so I suggest reading up on them.